# Using ModelBuilder and Inline substitution in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro

I am creating a model and was wondering whether it is possible to use inline substitution with variables that are a table of values or multiple values, shown below.

[image: Variable Data Type info box]

Comment: Yes. But the tool that you are feeding it into must expect a table .

Comment: @Hornbydd I'm assuming that the CalculateField tool wouldn't work with this. Am I correct?

Comment: If you read the Help page for that tool, specifically the [syntax section](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm#GUID-2E817E73-F1C8-42E3-9597-8BDEC11125E6) you can see what the _data types_ are for each parameter, this is what it is telling you. As you will discover there are no parameters that are a "table of values" type so you should deduce that the answer to your question is no.